# Transforming points into lines and calculating total distance in QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, expression, polyline-creation, points-to-line

I have a series of data, minutes and seconds that are associated with latitude and longitude. I would like to calculate the total distance within each minute, getting a value for each minute.

Now I use:

```
length(
    transform(
        make_line(
            geometry(get_feature_by_id(@layer, $id)),
            geometry(get_feature_by_id(@layer, $id+1))
            ),
        'EPSG:4326',
        'EPSG:23033'
        )
    )
```

Which, however, gives me the measure of each point. Does anyone know how to do?

[image]

I don't know why but when i try

```
aggregate(
    @layer,
    'sum',
    length(
        transform(
            make_line(
                geometry(get_feature_by_id(@layer, $id)),
                geometry(get_feature_by_id(@layer, $id+1))
                ),
            'EPSG:4326,
            'EPSG:23033'
            )
        )
    )
```

QGIS crashes

Comment: You forgot the simple quote `'` at the end of `'EPSG:4326`, that's why your syntax is not correct. Correct it and report back if it works like this.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add  `aggregate( @layer, 'sum', [your expression] )` and replace `[your expression]` with the expression you provided.

So the whole expression will look like, where apart from the first three and the last line, it is the expression you first provided (be sure the syntax is correct, include all single quotes `'`):

```
aggregate( 
    @layer, 
    'sum', 
    length (
        transform (
            make_line (
                geometry ( 
                    get_feature_by_id ( 
                        @layer, 
                        $id 
                    )
                ), 
                geometry ( 
                    get_feature_by_id ( 
                        @layer, 
                        $id+1 
                    )
                )
            ),
            'EPSG:4326', 
            'EPSG:23033'
        )
    )
)
```